# Upload a file to a site using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am using VBA to automate IE to upload a file to a site.

I found the button with the "file" type, but then seem to draw a blank when setting the path.

My current VBA:

```
Dim btnInput As Object ' MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim ElementCol As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
.
.
.
Set ElementCol = appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
     For Each btnInput In ElementCol
        If btnInput.Type = "file" Then
            btnInput.Value = "C:\temp\text.csv"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next btnInput
```

The HTML it is reading:

```
<div id="upload-assignments-modal" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Upload order changes</h3>
    </div>
    <form id="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="abcde"></div>


                <input type="hidden" name="partner" value="488" id="id_partner">

            <p><label for="id_feed_file">Feed file</label><input type="file" name="feed_file" id="id_feed_file"></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="feed_type" value="390" id="id_feed_type">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button name="action" value="upload" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

It finds the Type when stepping through and does go to set the value, but then there is no change on screen (I have the IE instance shown as visible for testing) and the file is not added.

Would I be right to assume that the "file" input type requires something other than `.Value` for it's input?

Comment: Just to add, I am using Excel 2007 and IE11 (although whatever solution would probably need to be used in XP as well, so IE8)

Comment: You can't. It's by design as a security feature, theoretically (I believe) to prevent rogue scripts uploading documents from a users computer

Comment: Wouldnt surprise me if it was a read-only attribute, but there must be another way to do it that is hopefully just as simple :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't. I've looked at this a long time ago and ended up posting the file directly to the server (which is a better solution anyway)

Comment: May well end up going that way. It's a valid solution at the end of the day but would like to try and get this method working more for the End Users benefit (at least if they see the actual site load up etc, they know its "doing something", plus this is a backup system for when the main method for uploading the file (FTP) does not work). Plus, getting this working would help satiate my own curiosity too :P

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @vivek no ive not found a way to work around the fact its a read only field.

Comment: any luck on this?

Comment: No change (although i no longer handle that code anymore). Would suggest looking into something like Selenium instead

Comment: I'm posting this for future seekers.
This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45382080/4037170

Comment: Be careful with using SendKeys, as there are pitfalls to be aware of. Things like the input window not having focus will break it, or if you are actively using the machine at the same time in other windows, keypresses can get sent elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
Set ElementCol = appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
     For Each btnInput In ElementCol
        If btnInput.Type = "file" Then
            btnInput.Value = "C:\temp\text.csv"
            btnInput.FireEvent ("onclick")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next btnInput
```

Comment: @bmgh1985 Is it possible to share the link?

Comment: Can't share the link as its on a site that you have to log on to. Have the logon part and the navigation part all set in the script alread, just need this little bit. Will change the OP to include a bit more HTML to make it a bit easier