# VBA:IE-How to assign pathname to file input tag without popup file upload form?

Tags: windows, vba, excel, internet-explorer, automation

I am currently doing automaiton for file uploading

Below is HTML tag for input file tag:

```
 <input name="file" title="Type the path of the file or click the Browse button to find the file." id="file" type="file" size="20">
```

And below is button HTML Tag:

```
<input name="Attach" title="Attach File (New Window)" class="btn" id="Attach" onclick="javascript:setLastMousePosition(event); window.openPopup('/widg/uploadwaiting.jsp', 'uploadWaiting', 400, 130, 'width=400,height=130,resizable=no,toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,directories=no,location=no,dependant=no', true);" type="submit" value="Attach File">
```

My VBA coding is:

```
Dim filee As Object
Set filee = mydoc.getElementById("file")
filee.Value = filenamepath

Set attach = mydoc.getElementsByName("Attach")
attach(0).Click
```

When I am running this coding, input filepath box not assign path name so i am getting chose file path.

Find attach screenshot.
[image]

Finally i have tried below code but that send key not executing

```
Dim filee As Object
    Set filee = mydoc.getElementById("file")
    filee.Click

obj.SetText filename
obj.PutInClipboard
SendKeys "^v"
SendKeys "{ENTER}"

Set attach = mydoc.getElementsByName("Attach")
    attach(0).Click

Set finall = mydoc.getElementsByName("cancel")
    finall(0).Click
```

Kindly tell me the windows API program to assign my file name directory in **fine name:** input box on opened **Choose File to Open** explorer and click the **open** button.

Comment: You cannot programmatically assign a value to an input of type "file".  Some pretty good security-related reason for that.

Comment: @TimWilliams   I have to do first browse.. click event after that shall i run this code or how to assign value after open file upload form ?

Comment: Kindly provide any other solution to do this automation .

Comment: @TimWilliams can i done this automation using Selenium webdriver with Firefox ?

Comment: I have no idea - I've never used Selenium.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed this issue by running external VBScript contain file path to set it on 'Choose File to Upload' pop up window using SendKeys method after send Enter Key to close this pop up, and this run successfully because the extranl VBScript run on another process so it will not stuck on VBA code.

Notes:
1- I dynamically create the external VBScript from VBA code and save it on Temp folder after that I run this script using WScript.Shell.Run to excute it on another thread
1- At the begining of the external VBScript I set 1 sec delay to be sure the 'Choose File to Upload' pop up window already opened from VBA.

And here is the complete code:

```
....
....

Set filee = mydoc.getElementById("file")

    CompleteUploadThread MyFilePath
    filee.Foucs
    filee.Click

....
....

Private Sub CompleteUploadThread(ByVal fName As String)
    Dim strScript As String, sFileName As String, wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    '---Create VBscript String---
    strScript = "WScript.Sleep 1000" & vbCrLf & _
                "Dim wsh" & vbCrLf & _
                "Set wsh = CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")" & vbCrLf & _
                "wsh.SendKeys """ & fName & """" & vbCrLf & _
                "wsh.SendKeys ""{ENTER}""" & vbCrLf & _
                "Set wsh = Nothing"
    '---Save the VBscript String to file---
    sFileName = wsh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%") & "\zz_automation.vbs"
    Open sFileName For Output As #1
    Print #1, strScript
    Close #1
    '---Execute the VBscript file asynchronously---
    wsh.Run """" & sFileName & """"
    Set wsh = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

As setting the value of a file input element is disabled due to security reasons, the "send keys" method seems to be the only option for automating file uploads using the IE API.

I just stumbled over the same problem that the code after the `Click` does not seem to be executed - that is, unless the dialog is closed. This indicates that the `Click` method is blocking, making it impossible to interact with the dialog from within the macro.

I could solve that by using a different method to open the dialog: by setting the focus to the file element with `Focus`, and sending the space key with `SendKeys`.

In your case, replace

```
filee.Click
```

with

```
filee.Focus
SendKeys " "
```

Answer (score 0):

leemes's method(Sending  key to the file selection button on IE) is an easy way to automate the file selection procedure.

In addition, if IEObject.Visible sometimes fails to give focus to the IE Window,
 we'd better send the IE window to the top-most position using Windows API before using 'SendKeys' like following:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As Any, ByVal lpWindowName As Any) As LongPtr
#Else
    Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As Any, ByVal lpWindowName As Any) As Long
#End If

Sub Test()

   'first create or get IE object
   Set IE= ...
   ...

   'second, send IE window to the foreground
   Dim TargetWnd
   TargetWnd = FindWindow("IEFrame", vbNullString)  'find IE window
   If TargetWnd = 0 Then Debug.Print "Window not found." 'Else Debug.Print TargetWnd
   SetForegroundWindow (TargetWnd)

   'sendkeys
   set filee = getElement....
   filee.Focus
   SendKeys " "     'send Space key instead of .Click method
   SendKeys "filePath"     ' "C:\path\filename"  ' Type-in the filename 
   SendKeys "{Enter}"    'closes the file dialog

   'finally submit       
   ...
   ...

end Sub
```