# VBA:WIndows API :How to assign file path to open windows?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, winapi, windows-api-code-pack

I am struggling in upload automation before i have tried with send key [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803863/vbaie-how-to-assign-pathname-to-file-input-tag-without-popup-file-upload-form?noredirect=1#comment57389083_34803863) after my question i have decided go with Windows API program and i refer lot of code in website i found only, how to find the my "Choose File to Upload" windows and click Open button, Now i don't know how to insert filename path to file name Edit text-box in open windows. Kindly tell me how to set the text value of an 'edit' control text box with the SendMessage() function.

Find attached screenshot for My IE file browse explorer.

[image]

Below my referred VBA coding FYI:

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias _
"GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Const BM_CLICK = &HF5&

Dim Ret As Long, ChildRet As Long, OpenRet As Long
Dim strBuff As String, ButCap As String

Sub Sample()
    '~~> Get the handle of the "File Download" Window
    Ret = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Choose File to Upload")

    If Ret <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Main Window Found"

        '~~> Get the handle of the Button's "Window"
        ChildRet = FindWindowEx(Ret, ByVal 0&, "Button", vbNullString)

        '~~> Check if we found it or not
        If ChildRet <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Child Window Found"

            '~~> Get the caption of the child window
            strBuff = String(GetWindowTextLength(ChildRet) + 1, Chr$(0))
            GetWindowText ChildRet, strBuff, Len(strBuff)
            ButCap = strBuff

            '~~> Loop through all child windows
            Do While ChildRet <> 0
                '~~> Check if the caption has the word "Open"
                '~~> For "Save" or "Cancel", replace "Open" with
                '~~> "Save" or "Cancel"
                If InStr(1, ButCap, "Open") Then
                    '~~> If this is the button we are looking for then exit
                    OpenRet = ChildRet
                    Exit Do
                End If

                '~~> Get the handle of the next child window
                ChildRet = FindWindowEx(Ret, ChildRet, "Button", vbNullString)
                '~~> Get the caption of the child window
                strBuff = String(GetWindowTextLength(ChildRet) + 1, Chr$(0))
                GetWindowText ChildRet, strBuff, Len(strBuff)
                ButCap = strBuff
            Loop

            '~~> Check if we found it or not
            If OpenRet <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "The Handle of Open Button is : " & OpenRet
                '~~> Click the button using Send Message
                SendMessage OpenRet, BM_CLICK, 0, 0
            Else
                MsgBox "The Handle of Open Button was not found"
            End If
        Else
             MsgBox "Child Window Not Found"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Window Not Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question. I also don't understand why you need to fake input to upload a file. Some HTTP code would be easier. And if you had to drive a browser why wouldn't you use automation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am trying to upload files in saleforce website automatically though VBA, so i have raised question and i got replay that some security reason cant chose file grammatically on File choosing  explorer window before that all process i can do automation but only i am struggling coding in choosing file in file browse screen.

Comment: Kindly refer this question [Same question](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/42d73061-dcfc-4ed2-97c3-92ba907fb5ed/automate-choose-file-to-upload-window-from-a-web-page?forum=winserverpowershell)

Comment: That doesn't ring true at all. Faking input sounds wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I Have found solution VBA program find Open window as "Choose File to Upload" , this window will popup in IE while uploading document in IE browser.It select file name edit box and assign full file path of file and click open button automatically.

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageByString Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias _
"GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long


Dim strBuff As String, ButCap As String
Public Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC
Public Const BM_CLICK = &HF5

Sub Sample()
hw = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Choose File to Upload")
op = FindWindowEx(hw, 0&, "Button", vbNullString)

 strBuff = String(GetWindowTextLength(op) + 1, Chr$(0))
 GetWindowText op, strBuff, Len(strBuff)
 ButCap = strBuff

    Do While op <> 0

                If InStr(1, ButCap, "Open") Then
                   OpenRet = op
                    Exit Do
                End If

Loop

hw1 = FindWindowEx(hw, 0&, "ComboBoxEx32", vbNullString)

hw2 = FindWindowEx(hw1, 0&, "ComboBox", vbNullString)

hw3 = FindWindowEx(hw2, 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)

Call SendMessageByString(hw3, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "C:\Users\kkath\Documents\mine\QC\2015\MAY\Email1.pdf")
Call SendMessage(OpenRet, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks :) Working perfectly