# Upload a file into html browser using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to upload a file to a web page, the following are the steps I followed:

1. Open the web page http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/input-file.html
2. Wait for until the page is getting loaded
3. In this webpage I am uploading the file into the first “Upload a File” browser.
4. Get the input element by tag name as “input”
5. Hit the “browse” button, since the paste potion is disabled.
6. Enter the file path in the “Choose File to Upload” window
7. Enter 
   After 5th step, I am not able to enter the file path in the “Choose File to Upload” window, looks like the macro is not supporting for this.

Here is my code :

```
Sub File_Test()

    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim ie As Object


    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/input-file.html"

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    Set HTMLDoc = ie.document
    Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")

    For Each HTMLButton In HTMLButtons
        If HTMLButton.Type = "file" Then
            HTMLButton.Click
            HTMLButton.Value = "C:\Documents\Test\Temp.txt"
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

And here's a screenshot:

[image: htmlquick]

Any suggestions?

===================================================

Here is another modified code but sill I am not able to enter the file name

Sub File_Test()

```
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim ie As Object
Dim WSshell

Set WSshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/input-file.html"

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = ie.document
Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each HTMLButton In HTMLButtons
    If HTMLButton.Type = "file" Then
        HTMLButton.Click

    With WSshell
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
            .AppActivate "Choose File to Upload"

            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    .SendKeys "C:\Documents\Test\Temp.txt"

            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")) 
            .SendKeys "~" 'Enter

        End With

        Exit For
    End If

Next
```

End Sub

Any idea? why sendkyes are not working?

Comment: Scripting a file name/path in a "file" input is not permitted for quite predictable security-related reasons.  You'll need to find some other way to do what you want.

Comment: Maybe see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42721288/manipulate-ie-with-vba-and-a-modal-form

Comment: Thanks Tim, I tried to modified my code as per the link you provided. but sill I am not able to enter file name. any suggestions?