# automatically choose picture from known location with folder picker on website

Tags: vba, web-scraping, sendkeys

I have an issue with folder picker which is opening on website to ask me upload a picture. I can login the website, can open the link the where browse link shows and also can click it. however, I cannot upload the known location and cannot click upload button. link is behind fw so all the links are hidden.

```
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Dim myElem As Variant
        ie.Visible = True

     With ie
         Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
        Dim t As Date, ele As Object
        t = Timer
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
     End With
    ie.document.getElementById("picture").Click
'this cell contains picture link
   Sheets("picture").Range("A12").Copy 

          With ie
     While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
     End With
    ie.document.getElementById("browse").Click
              With ie
     While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
     End With
'folder picker is active now and code should be written here 
         With ie
     While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
     End With
     ie.document.getElementById("upload").Click
     End With
```

manually, I can use ctrl+v and then enter and it is work but with macro I use below code and not worked for me.

```
SendKeys "^v", True
SendKeys "enter", True
```

Nothing solved yet, thanks your help.

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803863/vbaie-how-to-assign-pathname-to-file-input-tag-without-popup-file-upload-form

Comment: @sam thanks for the link but I have already seen it and tested it. unfortunately, nothing worked with folder picker screen.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you send the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. See [MSDN Guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys#remarks)

```
SendKeys "~", True '// Send {ENTER} key
```

currently you are *literally* sending the text `"enter"` to the window.

Comment: my prior issue is; I cannot paste locationt o folder picker screen. by the way thanks for the enter.