# Handle dialogue box

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

I came to ask for help because I am trying to automate a connection to a site to upload an excel file.

I am able to connect to the site, to authenticate myself and to reach the requested folder. My problem is when I trigger the click, a DialogBox window asks me to select the file.

1- How to insert the link of the folder containing the file in the address bar of the DialogBox and select the file?
2- Click on the Open button to attach the file?

Can you help me?
Thank you so much

N.B: I specify that it is the click that opens the dialog window, so I need a code to interact with this DialogBox.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5j9s.jpg)

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument

Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Visible=True
IE.Navigate "https://myserver.com"
While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
With HTMLDoc
.getElementById("A_username").Value = "myusername"
.getElementById("A_password").Value = "mypassword"
End With

IE.document.getElementById("login").Click
While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
IE.Navigate "https://myserver.com/link.folder
While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
With HTMLDoc
.getElementById("name").Value ="foldername" 
End With
IE.document.getElementById("addButton").Click
While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
IE.Navigate "https://myserver.com/link.folderfind1
IE.document.getElementById("Button").Click
While IE.Busy: DoEvents:Wend
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
```

Comment: Try SendKeys https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys

Comment: I tried various approaches to set the file in file upload control using VBA IE Automation but it looks like we cannot automate the select file dialog using VBA and for some security reasons we cannot directly set the value for file upload control. These are the things that I had tested on my side. [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45382080/10309381), [Link2](https://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_uploadvbaie/)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: If possible then you can try to check for any UI automating APIs that can let you interact with the Select file dialog. After selecting the file, you can continue with your VBA IE automation code.